# OkHttpClient offline cache

Tags: caching, offline, okhttp

I'm trying to implement response caching using OkHttpClient, but i'm a bit confused. To do this, i'm using Interceptor like this:

```
final Interceptor interceptor = chain -> {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if (isOnline()) {
        int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
        response = response.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                .build();
    } else {
        int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
        response = response.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Cache-Control","public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                .build();
    }
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        response = response.cacheResponse();
    }
    return response;
}
mClient.networkInterceptors().add(interceptor);
mClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);
```

But i'm getting UnknownHostException if there's no internet connection. But i want to get cached response. How to deal with it?